# Detecting magnets regardless of polarity

Tags: hall-effect, detection, matrix, reed-switch

I'd like to build large matrix of sensors to detect objects placed on it. I can place magnet or metal inside detected pieces. I tried to use reed switch and hall sensors. Hall sensors seems like better option, but downside is I can detect only one polarity and objects might be placed any side(top or bottom). Problem with reed switch is, if I place object, sometimes I get response from few reed switches.

Is there any cheap solution to detect objects which might be placed next to each other? Was thinking about two hall sensors placed side by side, but thought I ask here to see if someone had similar problem.

Comment: Search for "omnipolar" Hall effect switches.  They're about 50 cents each in quantity which is tolerably cheap.

Comment: Nice! I didn't even knew there is already something like that. I'll have to look for cheapest one, cause the one I found is like 4 times more expensive. It might be cheaper to just connect 2 unipolar ones. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: You might consider making a checkerboard arrangement of sensors aligned along different axes.  By combining data from adjacent sensors you should be able to infer location (where is signal strongest) and might be able to get rotation angle (relative strength of the peak field along each of the two axes).  Multiple pieces would result in multi-modal sensor readout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Hall sensors seems like better option, but downside is I can detect only one polarity

Hall sensors that work with either polarity of magnet is definitely a thing.  Every manufacturer has their own nomenclature; DigiKey uses "omnipolar" and "north, south" in their selection table.

The [Diodes, Inc., AH1809-Z-7](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/AH1809.pdf) is an example that I picked nearly at random, but there's a fairly wide selection.

Go shopping!  It's out there!

Comment: Thanks! I'll mark this as an answer. Didn't knew there something like that. For what I saw it's 4 times more expensive, but I'll keep looking for cheaper one. If I won't find I think I'll try to build the matrix with 2 unipolar sensors. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Using two unipolar sensors would work -- if you're making a product in quantity, only paying for the time & trouble to put one chip on the board instead of two would justify the cost (which is why they sell).